# Converting the derivative into a particular form.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have found the derivative of a function $$y = \frac{(x+1)^2}{(x+2)^4},$$  which is $$\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{2x(x+1)}{(x+2)^5}.$$ 
However how would you express this derivative into the form below:

$$ \Big(\frac{a}{a+1}+\frac{b}{b+2}\Big)y$$ stating the values of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Could you give some intuition or context as to where the problem comes from?

Comment: Not  knowing $y$, we can't. How did you get this value?

Comment: Assuming that $a = a(x)$ and $b = b(x)$?

Comment: I would have provided an image however i need to have 10 reputations in order to do so.

Comment: [Cross Post](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/205231/converting-the-derivative-into-a-particular-form) on PSE. Both questions seem to have been created within 2 minutes of each other.

Comment: Just take logarithmic derivative of y. $\frac{y'}{y}=\frac{d}{dx}\log y$

Comment: Thank you very much uranix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can't be done without additional assumptions, since 
$$
y' = -2 \frac{x(x+1)}{(x+2)^5}
$$
determines $y(x)$ up to an arbitrary constant term
$$
y(x) = f(x) + C.
$$
But solving the DE by separation
$$
dy = -2 \frac{x(x+1)dx}{(x+2)^5}\\
x(x+1) = x^2 + x = (x^2 + 4x + 4) - (3x + 4) = 
(x+2)^2 - 3(x+2) + 2\\
y = -2\int^x \frac{[(x+2)^2 - 3(x+2) + 2]dx}{(x+2)^5} = 
C-2 \left[
-\frac{1}{2(x+2)^2}
+\frac{3}{3(x+2)^3}
-\frac{2}{4(x+2)^4}
\right] = \\
= C + \frac{1}{(x+2)^2}  - \frac{2}{(x+2)^3} + \frac{1}{(x+2)^4} = 
C + \frac{(x+2)^2 - 2(x+2) +1}{(x+2)^4} = \\
= C + \frac{(x+1)^2}{(x+2)^4}
$$
and assuming case when $C=0$ gives
$$
y' = -2 \frac{x(x+1)}{(x+2)^5} = A\frac{(x+1)^2}{(x+2)^4} = Ay
$$
so
$$
A = \frac{-2x}{(x+1)(x+2)}.
$$
Now we need to solve
$$
\frac{-2x}{(x+1)(x+2)} = A = \frac{a}{a+1} + \frac{b}{b+2} = \frac{2ab+2a+b}{(a+1)(b+2)}
$$
for $a$ and $b$ which reduces to
$$
2ab+2a+b = -2x\lambda\\
(a+1)(b+2) = (x+1)(x+2)\lambda
$$
for some $\lambda \neq 0$. Since it is a system of two equaitons with three unknowns ($a, b, \lambda$) it may have infinitely many solutions, none of them are simple.

But if the problem is to express $y'$  in form (note the denominators are changed)
$$
\left(\frac{a}{x+1} + \frac{b}{x+2}\right)y = 
\frac{2a+b+(a+b)x}{(x+1)(x+2)} y
$$
then it reduces to solving
$$
2a+b+ax+bx=-2x
$$
for $a,b$ and the equation has a solution with $a,b$ being just constants 
$$
a+b = -2\\
2a+b = 0\\
a = 2, b = -4.
$$

Comment: Good answer, but I'd suggest that you make your answers only as good as the quality of the question. In this case the quality is poor, so a simple wolfram link would've done the trick.

Comment: Two wrongs don't make a right, @Zach466920.

Comment: @NormalHuman Uhmm, what? Comments with links to useful information are generally considered good. These questions, there's a cross-post, don't deserve this kind of attention. My comment is on *question answering on meritocracy* versus *the low hanging fruit method*

Comment: I have made an edit

Comment: @NormalHuman Yes. Perhaps a difference of opinion? I believe that answers can be comments and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you very much uranix

Answer (score 2):

You can get the form of the derivative you want by using logarithmic differentiation.
You have $$y=(x+1)^2(x+2)^{-4}$$
$$\Rightarrow\ln y=2\ln(x+1)-4\ln(x+2)$$
$$\Rightarrow\frac 1yy'=\frac{2}{x+1}-\frac{4}{x+2}$$
$$\Rightarrow y'=\left(\frac{2}{x+1}-\frac{4}{x+2}\right)y$$